# Selective operation on Pandas DataFrame using loc without overwriting non-selected rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to apply an arithmetic operation to select rows of a Pandas DataFrame, with the selection depending on another column.

I first tried defining a function and using `apply` to calculate the values, but this was prohibitively slow, since the function logic is I guess evaluated for every row.

It is much quicker to apply the operation using `loc`, but when I apply this successively, the non-selected rows are overwritten with NaN each time.

An illustrative example would be:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 0.1], [1, 0.2], [1, 0.3], [2, 0.4], [2, 0.5]], columns=["class", "size"]
)
new_df
#    class  size
#    1      0.1
#    1      0.2
#    1      0.3
#    2      0.4
#    2      0.5
```

Say I would like to square the size value for all rows with class == 2, and cube it for all rows with class == 1.

The target DataFrame would be

```
#    class  size oper_size
#    1      0.1  0.001
#    1      0.2  0.008
#    1      0.3  0.027
#    2      0.4  0.16
#    2      0.5  0.25
```

However, if I do:

```
new_df["oper_size"] = new_df["size"].loc[new_df["class"] == 1] ** 3
new_df["oper_size"] = new_df["size"].loc[new_df["class"] == 2] ** 2
```

Then the resulting dataframe is:

```
#  class  size  oper_size
#      1   0.1        NaN
#      1   0.2        NaN
#      1   0.3        NaN
#      2   0.4       0.16
#      2   0.5       0.25
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create dictionary for each value of `class`, so possible use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for new Series and then only use exponentiation by `**`:

```
new_df["oper_size"] = new_df["size"] ** new_df['class'].map({1:3, 2:2})
print (new_df)
   class  size  oper_size
0      1   0.1      0.001
1      1   0.2      0.008
2      1   0.3      0.027
3      2   0.4      0.160
4      2   0.5      0.250
```

**Detail**:

```
print (new_df['class'].map({1:3, 2:2}))
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    2
4    2
Name: class, dtype: int64
```

If some values are not matched like here last row you can replace all values to some number, e.g. `0` or some column, e.g. `size`:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 0.1], [1, 0.2], [1, 0.3], [2, 0.4], [3, 0.5]], columns=["class", "size"]
)


new_df["oper_size1"]=(new_df["size"] ** new_df['class'].map({1:3, 2:2})).fillna(0)
new_df["oper_size2"]=(new_df["size"] ** new_df['class'].map({1:3, 2:2})).fillna(new_df["size"])

print (new_df)
   class  size  oper_size1  oper_size2
0      1   0.1       0.001       0.001
1      1   0.2       0.008       0.008
2      1   0.3       0.027       0.027
3      2   0.4       0.160       0.160
4      3   0.5       0.000       0.500
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the rows you want to replace, using `loc`. E.g.

```
new_df.loc[new_df["class"] == 1, "oper_size"] = new_df[new_df["class"] == 1, "oper_size"] ** 3
```

Or define a mask which can be used for both sides:

```
mask_1 = new_df["class"] == 1
new_df.loc[mask_1, "oper_size"] = new_df[mask_1, "oper_size"] ** 3
```

Alternatively, you can also use `numpy.where` to differentiate between 2 cases:

```
new_df['oper_size'] = np.where(new_df['class'] == 1, 
                               new_df['size']**3,
                               new_df['size']**2)
new_df
```

```
   class  size  oper_size
0      1   0.1      0.001
1      1   0.2      0.008
2      1   0.3      0.027
3      2   0.4      0.160
4      2   0.5      0.250
```

Comment: Hi mcsoini, thanks for the response - very helpful.